# Select subset of unique random records in R

Tags: r, random, unique

I want to select a subset of n random records from a dataframe but I want unique values based on a column. For instance, from the dataset

```
X1 X2
1  4
1  5
1  6
2  44
2  55
3  444
3  555
3  666
3  777
```

From this for n=3, I do not want something like:

```
X1  X2
 3 777
 3 555
 2  55
```

where two records are from the same seed X1 = 3
But I want something like:

```
X1  X2
 1  5
 2  44
 3  555
```

How do I do this?

I tried the following:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,4,5,6,44,55,444,555,666,777,4444,5555,6666,10,20,30,40,50),nrow=17,ncol=2))
df.colnames = c("x1","x2")
df[sample(nrow(df),3),]
```

But it doesn't seem to give me what I want. How do I tweak sample to get what I want? Or should I use a different function for subsetting

**Edit** Please note that my df is going to be about 50 million records and I may want to sample 1 million of these. (like 1 m unique data points). Which method would be the most efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
 set.seed(1)
 aggregate(X2~X1, df, sample, 1)
 #   X1  X2
 #1  1   4
 #2  2  44
 #3  3 666
```

Or using `data.table`

```
 set.seed(1)
 setDT(df)[, list(X2=sample(X2,1)), by=X1]
 #  X1  X2
 #1:  1   4
 #2:  2  44
 #3:  3 666
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `stratified` function from my "splitstackshape" package, like this:

```
library(splitstackshape)
set.seed(1) ## so you can reproduce this
stratified(df, "X1", 1)
#    X1  X2
# 1:  1   4
# 2:  2  44
# 3:  3 666
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `sample_n` from "dplyr":

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1) ## again, just to reproduce this
df %>% group_by(X1) %>% sample_n(1)
# Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
# Groups: X1
# 
#   X1  X2
# 1  1   4
# 2  2  44
# 3  3 666
```

---

Regarding your note, here are some quick timings on my system for 20M rows:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(X1 = sample(1000000, 20000000, TRUE), 
                 X2 = rnorm(20000000))
dim(df)
# [1] 20000000        2

system.time(df %>% group_by(X1) %>% sample_n(1))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 39.687   0.365  40.583 
system.time(as.data.table(df)[, list(X2=sample(X2,1)), by=X1])
#   user  system elapsed 
# 10.792   0.156  11.033 
system.time(stratified(df, "X1", 1))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 12.351   0.455  12.895
```

(Of course, `stratified` will also give you other bells and whistles out of the box, like dynamic subsetting, taking samples proportional to the size of the groups, and so on :-) )

Comment: Ah, it seems that I added my idea when you updated your answer!

Answer (score 3):

This could be another way using `dplyr`.

```
group_by(df, X1) %>%
sample_n(1)

#  X1  X2
#1  1   5
#2  2  55
#3  3 777
```